# How to delete records in 2 tables with just 1 DELETE command in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Table structure model:

Table: user

```
id
name
email
```

Table: employee

```
id
user_id
cpf
```

We have these two tables in the database, how to make a script, which takes the id of the user table and checks in the employee table, if the user_id are the same, if it is the same it deletes the record from the two tables, if it is not the same it deletes the record only from the user table

**Rota**

```
Route::delete('/plano/{id}',[ChangePlanController::class, 'destroy'])->name('plan.destroy');
```

**views**

```
<form action="{{ route('plan.destroy', $profissional->user_id)}}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit"  class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900" >Excluir</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    if(!$user = UserEmployee::find($id))
     
    return redirect()->route('plan.searchUsers');
    
    $user->delete();
    
    return redirect()->route('plan.searchUsers');
}
```

Comment: Well I believe that is what cascading is meant to do.

Comment: It can be done either by two delete commands in one transaction, or by setting up FK with ON DELETE CASCADE in the database https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/ Which approach do you prefer?

Comment: the bank has no relationship, otherwise you could use cascade

Comment: What do you mean `has no relationship`, if you do not add the relationship it will have none, correct. I’m just wondering what is holding you back to add a relationship?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user ->delete()
employee::where("id", $user->id )->delete();
return redirect()->route('users.index')`
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this method on your controller**

```
    if($user= UserEmployee::findOrFail($id)){ 
           $user->user()->delete();
            $user->delete();
            return redirect()->back("message","Deleted");
    }else{
           return redirect()->back("message","Not Deleted");
}
```

**`Please Make Sure yor model have Relationship if not please try to make Relationship b/n Tables`**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).